# Impacts on changing the sender domain name

Tags: marketing-cloud, sender-authentication-package, ip

I have a question about changing sender domain name.

Let's say our client have the following "Sender authenticated name" on SFMC : "communicationabc.abcenterprise.com" (they have a SAP - Sender authenticated package)

They want to change it for "communication.abcenterprise.com".
They used to use that domain name in their previous emailing platform before moving to SFMC, and they would like to be able to use that one again.

What should be done to get a new or another Sender authenticated domain name on SFMC?
If they change their sender authenticated name, does it involve a new IP address that will have to be warmed up?

What should be done first if the sender domain name they want to use, has been already used in the past on their previous email platform ?

In general, we would like to understand all the impacts (in terms of extra costs, extra IP, SAP, IP warm up, deliverability, email delivery, etc...) and all the steps that need to be done for changing the sender authenticated domain (or having another one).

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They could simply use a Private Domain, and send from this one - keeping the old SAP in place. This is a cheaper option. However links and images will still be wrapped in the old domain.

They can go all in, and get a new SAP, keeping the existing IP address. This is more costly, but will provide a consistent brand experience. If SSLs have been purchased, they will probably need to purchase a new set, to secure the updated SAP domain.

A complete IP warmup is not required, especially if old SAP domain is kept. If they choose to change everything but the IP, there still shouldn’t be much impact on  deliverability, however I will still keep an eye on bounce and open rates for the first week after the change, to make sure no ISPs have issues delivering the mails to inboxes. Exact definition of IP vs domain impact is not set in stone, however there is a shift towards more attention to sender domain based reputation.

Should a decision be made on a new SAP, there is a number of actions to be performed by you/your client:

- Any custom HTML Paste emails, or HTML blocks, will need to be manually updated
- Any AMPscript containing URL references would need to be updated
- Cloud Pages and MicroSites would have to be rebuilt on the new domain

The prior SAP domain will remain in place for 60 days, but after this point, old links in emails and references to Cloud Pages on old domain will cease working.